# Does this matrix exist? A commonly encountered puzzle

Tags: linear-algebra, trace, pseudoinverse

Suppose we have $n\times n$ positive definite matrix $S$ and $n\times n$ positive semi-definite matrix $Y$. Let $R$ be a diagonal matrix of indicators, such that WLOG $RSR$ is a principle submatrix of $S$ padded by zeros. Does there exist a matrix $\Psi$ such that

$$
tr(Y[RSR]^+)=tr(\Psi S^{-1})
$$

where $\psi$ is not a function of $S$? If so, what is $\Psi$?

Possibly relevant prior answers:

- [Are there any decompositions of a symmetric matrix that allow for the inversion of any submatrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208001/are-there-any-decompositions-of-a-symmetric-matrix-that-allow-for-the-inversion)
- [Block inverse of symmetric matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182309/block-inverse-of-symmetric-matrices)
- [Computing the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of a submatrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429349/computing-the-moore-penrose-pseudoinverse-of-a-submatrix)

I've spent some time trying to do this with block-wise matrix inversion but so far that has been a dead end. Specifically, it is true that

$$
[RSR]^+=R S^{-1}R-R S^{-1} Q [Q S^{-1} Q]^+ Q S^{-1} R
$$

where $Q=I-R$ but this doesn't seem to suggest a tractable solution.

Context:
This is question is related to handling missing data in a Normal-Inverse Wishart model, with $R$ masking some of the data points.